# how to verify curl with ssl with key without password

Tags: php, html, ajax, soap, php-curl

Update: I have updated code with certificate file path now & it's working but I am getting a cURL Error `#:unable to set private key file: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\themes\alfalah-theme\certificate.pem' type PEM`

Previously I had format issue which I resolved by supplying the key in `PEM` format and I now need to set `private key` for file which I don't know.

```
$xml_data = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:epr="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ePRCintegrationService.BLL" xmlns:epr1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ePRCintegrationService">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:Get_PRCRequest>
     <tem:Refnumber>
        <epr:Benename>'.$Benename.'</epr:Benename>
        <epr:Referencenumber>'.$Referencenumber.'</epr:Referencenumber>  
        <epr:RegisterMobilenumber>'.$RegisterMobilenumber.'</epr:RegisterMobilenumber>
        <epr:Registeremail>'.$Registeremail.'</epr:Registeremail>
     </tem:Refnumber>
     <tem:ApiCred>
        <epr1:APIAgentid>WEbUSER</epr1:APIAgentid>
        <epr1:APIPassword>uc/KwgjodHMYIu/DkS/ZJBBFXWmkv2ptAChBjOW4u+0=</epr1:APIPassword>
        <epr1:APIUserId>webAPI</epr1:APIUserId>
     </tem:ApiCred>
  </tem:Get_PRCRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';



$url            = "https://remittex.bankalfalah.com/ePRCintegrationService/Service1.svc";
$cert_file      = getcwd().'\cert.pem';
$cert_password  = 'abcd@123456789';
$User_Agent     = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
$headers        = array(
    "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "Accept: application/xml",
    "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_data)
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://remittex.bankalfalah.com/ePRCintegrationService/Service1.svc",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 30,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $User_Agent,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $xml_data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $headers,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT         => $cert_file
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

var_dump($info);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {

    $xml = $response;
    $xml = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", '$1$2$3', $xml);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $responseArray = json_decode($json, true); // true to have an array, false for an object
    // print_r($responseArray);
    // print_r($response);

    foreach ($responseArray as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                echo $v['Get_PRCRequestResult'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to add another configuration parameter to your curl request - `CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD` which is `"The password required to use the CURLOPT_SSLCERT certificate"`

Comment: Firstly thanks to clear my question be reformaing it but, i think the password is not required since i just gave it rndom password it still says unable to set private key

Comment: ok - never had need to use those options before so it was a guess ( a bad one perhaps ) - there are various `OpenSSL` functions in PHP - one of which is `openssl_get_privatekey`

Comment: you are right if i remove ssl verification i get no response even my ip is going to server it just not returning  me anything if there is something need to be resolve in Soap let me know i will be very thankful to you sir.